# Need help understanding/coding with Settings API

Tags: theme-options, options

So I did something like below, but I get just (I am expecting a Facebook textbox?)

[image]

I hope its not too messy. I am new to Settings API ...

```
add_action('admin_init', function() {
    register_setting('elem_opts', 'elem_opts', 'elem_validate_opts');
  add_settings_section('elem_opts_form', 'Elements Theme Options', 'elem_opts_form_cb', 'elems_opts');
  add_settings_field('elem_opts_form', 'Facebook', 'elem_opts_social_fb_cb', 'elems_opts', 'elem_opts_form');
});

function elem_opts_social_fb_cb() {
  $opts = get_option('elem_opts');
  if (empty($opts) || !is_array($opts)) {
    $opts = array();
  }
  ?>
  <input type="text" name="elem_opts[fb]" value="<?php echo $opts['fb'] ? $opts['fb'] : ''; ?>" />
  <?php
}

add_action('admin_menu', function() {
    add_theme_page('Elements Options', 'Elements Options', 'manage_options', 'elem_opts', 'elem_opts_cb');
});

function elem_validate_opts($input) {
  return $input;
}

function elem_opts_form() {
  ?>
  <p>Enable social network links, by entering your username for the respective social networks</p>
  <?php
}

function elem_opts_cb() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Elements Theme Options</h2>

        <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <?php 
            settings_fields('elem_opts'); 
            do_settings_sections('elem_opts');
            ?>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save changes" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: And where's the Q?

Comment: It appears that the problem is that his settings section/setting field aren't being output - and thus, the question is: why?

Comment: @kaiser, From the code, I am expecting the form to have a facebook textbox. Its not there. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some of the callback functions and the ID's mixed up, try this:

```
add_action('admin_init', function() {
    register_setting('elem_opts', 'elem_opts', 'elem_validate_opts');
    add_settings_section('elem_opts_form1', 'Elements Theme Options', 'elem_opts_form', 'elem_opts');
    add_settings_field('elem_opts_form', 'Facebook', 'elem_opts_social_fb_cb', 'elem_opts', 'elem_opts_form1');
});

function elem_opts_social_fb_cb() {
  $opts = get_option('elem_opts');
  if (empty($opts) || !is_array($opts)) {
    $opts = array();
  }
  ?>
  <input type="text" name="elem_opts[fb]" value="<?php echo $opts['fb'] ? $opts['fb'] : ''; ?>" />
  <?php
}

add_action('admin_menu', function() {
    add_theme_page('Elements Options', 'Elements Options', 'manage_options', 'elem_opts', 'elem_opts_cb');
});

function elem_validate_opts($input) {
  return $input;
}

function elem_opts_form() {
  ?>
  <p>Enable social network links, by entering your username for the respective social networks</p>
  <?php
}

function elem_opts_cb() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Elements Theme Options</h2>

        <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <?php 
            settings_fields('elem_opts'); 
            do_settings_sections('elem_opts');
            ?>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save changes" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

which give me this:

[image]

and for next time try to use different names and ids for each function, callback, section and page slug.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I had typos etc ... elem became elems, and like you said messed up IDs and callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

See here for reference: [Incorporating the Settings API in WordPress Themes](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/). In particular, see Page 10.

Your first problem, though I don't know that it would cause the form section/field not to output, is that you pass the same string as the first argument to both `add_settings_section()` and `add_settings_field()`. For `add_settings_field()`, the first argument is the ID of the *setting field itself*, so it probably shouldn't be the same thing as the first argument passed to `add_settings_section()`, which is the ID of the *settings section*.

Comment: Thanks for alerting me to that. http://pastie.org/1984876 better? its still not working tho ...

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure that would cause the form section/fields not to output. I need to dig in a bit deeper. I will take a look, and update my answer with whatever else I find.