# Theme Options page with tabs

Tags: theme-options, options, api

I have a theme that I'm developing from an HTML template I have. I'm also designing an options page along with a plethora of plugins built-into the theme itself. I've chosen a tabbed interface and I'm trying to learn how to use WordPress' Settings API.

I'm using a class structure for the theme's functions. The following is the declaration of registering settings and whatnot.

```
public function __admin_init()
{
    register_setting( 'cncfps_twitter', 'cncfps_twitter_options', array( &$this, 'wp_cncfps_twitter' ) );
    add_settings_section( 'cncfps_twitter', 'Twitter', array( &$this, 'wp_cncfps_twitter' ), 'cncfps' );
    add_settings_field( 'cncfps_twitter_consumer_key', 'Consumer Key', array( &$this, 'twitter_consumer_key' ), 'cncfps', 'cncfps_twitter' );
    add_settings_field( 'cncfps_twitter_consumer_secret', 'Consumer Secret', array( &$this, 'twitter_consumer_secret' ), 'cncfps', 'cncfps_twitter' );
    add_settings_field( 'cncfps_twitter_apikey', 'API Key', array( &$this, 'twitter_apikey' ), 'cncfps', 'cncfps_twitter' );
}

public function wp_cncfps_twitter()
{
    // TODO: wut. ?!?!
    echo "what is this?";
}

public function twitter_consumer_key()
{
    echo "Hello";
}

public function twitter_consumer_secret()
{
    echo "World";
}
```

**When I want to display the fields as shown [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18555/need-help-understanding-coding-with-settings-api), I don't see a thing. The following is how I attempt to display them. I did follow a [few](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/4/) [tutorials](http://ottodestruct.com/blog/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/) but it's just not clicking in my brain for some reason.**

```
settings_fields('cncfps_twitter');
do_settings_sections('cncfps_twitter');
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `do_settings_section()` function call needs to correspond to the `$optiongroup` argument you pass to `register_setting()`. To see how all of the myriad functions fit together, see [page 10 of my tutorial](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/4/).

It does get fairly confusing trying to follow how the various functions string together.

EDIT:

You do appear to be using the option group properly. Can you clarify what is/is not "clicking" for you? You mention in the title that you want to use a tabbed interface, but the question text itself doesn't really indicate where exactly you're running into difficulty.

Comment: The screenshot should be quite clear. Nothing shows up and the only thing that I can believe is that it doesn't support class-structure. :/

Comment: What screenshot?

Comment: The one in my post? O.o

Comment: That's really strange; no screenshot appeared for me in your post, until this morning...

Comment: The difficulty I'm running into is the that nothing shows when I call the `do_settings_section`/`settings_fields` functions :\

Comment: I **highly** recomment Chip Bennett's tutorial as I found it's the best comprehensive tutorial for Settings API.

Comment: Quick follow up question, did they change it in a wordpress version recently? I noticed the [arguments changed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field) on `add_settngs_field`. It seems kinda backwards to echo your own fields imo, lol.

Comment: To what changes are you referring? I've not noticed any. *"It seems kinda backwards to echo your own fields "* - I'm not sure what you mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

I also had a blank page when I tried implementing the suggested code. For some reason, my site didn't like all the double-quotes in this section (from page 3 of Chip's tutorial):

```
if ( $tab == $current ) :
    $links[] = "<a class="nav-tab nav-tab-active" href="?page=oenology-    settings&tab=$tab">$name</a>";
else :
    $links[] = "<a class="nav-tab" href="?page=oenology-settings&tab=$tab">$name</a>";
endif;
```

I had to change it and make use of single quotes:

```
if ( $tab == $current ) :
    $links[] = '<a class="nav-tab nav-tab-active" href="?page=oenology-settings&tab=' . $tab . '">' . $name . '</a>';
else :
    $links[] = '<a class="nav-tab" href="?page=oenology-settings&tab=' . $tab . '">' . $name . '</a>';
endif;
```

That seemed to fix it for me. I'm not sure if that's the same problem you're facing though.